# Login issue in laravel 5

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I am trying to create login in laravel 5.But each time i got this error `These credentials do not match our records`.My code is like this :

Route page:

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

Contoller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

     /**
     * Show the application login form.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getLogin()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    /**
     * Handle a login request to the application.
     *
     * @param  LoginRequest  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function postLogin(LoginRequest $request)
    {

      if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) 
        {
            return redirect('/dash-board');
        }

        return redirect('/login')->withErrors([
            'email' => 'The credentials you entered did not match our records. Try again?',
        ]);
    }

}
```

And my view form action is like this :

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://bucketspms-plumnetworks.c9.io/auth/login" method="POST">
```

I am new to Laravel so confuse why its not allow me to login.

Comment: I assume you were able to sucessfully register that user with that password?

Comment: No i have created table with command then insert manual entry.But i create password with Hash method of laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **$email and $password**, but these variables are not set, you should use **$request->input('email') and $request->input('password')** in this function

```
public function postLogin(LoginRequest $request)
{

  if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')])) 
    {
        return redirect('/dash-board');
    }

    return redirect('/login')->withErrors([
        'email' => 'The credentials you entered did not match our records. Try again?',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: When you create the user, you should use Hash::make('your-password') for the password field. Auth::attempt looking for the hashed password in the database.